# What is the type of XPath Expression

Tags: xml, xpath

I am bit confuse about type of XPath Expression:

I have XPath Expressions as

```
/*/text()? What is its type?
count(/*/text()) what is its type?
```

what is the difference between both types.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `/*/text()` returns a node set (XPath 1.0) or sequence of nodes (XPath 2.0) consisting of all the text nodes that are immediate children of the document element.  It does not include text nodes that are children of other elements, i.e. given a document

```
<root>foo<child>bar</child>baz</root>
```

`/*/text()` would be a set of *two* text nodes, one containing the text `foo` and the other containing `baz`.

The `count` function returns the number of nodes in a node set (XPath 1.0)/items in a sequence (XPath 2.0).  In XPath 1.0 all numbers are treated as double precision floating point, in XPath 2.0 [`count` has the more specific return type of `xs:integer`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-count).